# Calculate $\int_{p}^{p+2} \left \lfloor{\sqrt{x}}\right \rfloor dx,$ for the sequence of the first $100$ prime pairs $(p,p+2)$

Tags: analysis, elementary-number-theory, definite-integrals, prime-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

This question is only a curiosity, that I asked myself few minutes ago.

Let the **arithmetical function** $$f(n)=\int_0^n \left \lfloor{\sqrt{x}}\right \rfloor dx,$$
where $\left \lfloor{x}\right \rfloor$ is the **floor function** satisfying thus $x=\left \lfloor{x}\right \rfloor+\{x\}$, being $\{x\}$ the **fractional part function**. Thus when $n$ is a positive integer (in fact I've interested only in such case, is a positive integer) then $f(n)$ is a positive integer.

Now for prime pairs $n_k$ and $n_k+2$, that is a prime $n_k=p$ with $p+2$ also a **prime number**, I am interesting to get the sequence of the first (say $100$) differences 
$$f(p+2)-f(p).$$

> **Question.** Can you provide us the sequence $$f(n_k+2)-f(n_k)$$ when $1\leq k\leq 100$, with $n_k$ a prime number and $n_k+2$ also a prime number? **Thanks in advance.**

Curently I have no good abilities in computations with online calculators or computers, thus I am asking this with the purpose to discard a pattern that I've observed in the firsts pairs. Perhaps my question also is not interesting by the values that takes previous arithmetical function. I want to explore it with this exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick Mathematica program can generate this sequence:

```
primelist = Table[Prime[i], {i, 1, 1000}];
twinprimes = Select[primelist, MemberQ[primelist, (# + 2)] &, 100];
Table[Integrate[Floor[Sqrt[x]], {x, i, i + 2}], {i, twinprimes}]

{3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 20, 20, 22, 24, 26, 26, 28, 30, 30, 32,
32, 34, 36, 40, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 48, 50, 50, 56, 56, 56, 58, 58,
62, 64, 64, 64, 66, 66, 70, 70, 70, 72, 72, 74, 76, 76, 76, 80, 80,
80, 82, 82, 84, 86, 86, 86, 88, 88, 90, 90, 90, 90, 92, 92, 94, 94,
96, 96, 96, 100, 100, 102, 102, 104, 104, 104, 104, 108, 108, 110,
112, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 116, 116, 116, 116, 118, 118, 118, 118,
120, 122, 122}
```

Comment: Very thanks much, now I see that I was wrong because there are no the sequence $2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16, 18, 20...$ as was my belief.

Answer (score 1):

As the number between twin primes is never a square ($p+1=m^2$ would imply $p=(m+1)(m-1)$) except for the first twin prime pair, $\lfloor\sqrt x\rfloor$ is constant on $(p,p+2)$.
Thus you really just ask for $1+2\sum\lfloor \sqrt p\rfloor$ where $p$ runs over the lower partner of the first 100 prime pairs (that's, $3,5,11,17,29,\ldots,3821$); the $+1$ is to correct for the exceptional case described for the first twin pair. Numerically, the result seems to be $$7237.$$

Comment: Very thanks much, I try understand the translation from the enflish of your answer. Then you say that the patter is obvious or well that there are no such pattern in the cited sequence?

Comment: Very thanks much I've accepted previous answer, but yours answer is also very valuable.